# No funds after copying keystore files

Tags: mist, keystore

I believe i correctly backed up the keystore files, however, once I copied the keystore file back into my new ethereum directory, it doesnt show my funds in my wallet. Do i need to enter my password somewhere? Or is it because the wallet is not synchronised yet? thank you

Comment: If your wallet isn't fully synced, that'll be why.

Comment: This will almost certainly be a dupe of a previous question, though I can't find a suitable one right now...

Answer (score 1):

Copying keystore folder(your private keys) gives you only the access to your account (send/receive) the amount is stored in the blockchain(chaindata folder) so you need to synchronize your client or you can use an online wallet like https://www.myetherwallet.com

Comment: having a similiar issue - I can "see" my account, blockchain is synced since two days. What does it mean to "synchronize client"?